# Cant see mapreduce wordcount output file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I followed michael noll's tutorial to download and install hadoop. I also ran the wordcount example. But I can not see the output of the same. When I see the files in the dfs i get all the list of files that I have

[image]

But when I cat these files i get an error:

[image]

Wondering what went wrong there...

Comment: better recheck your setup. you could try hadoop -dfs touchz file ; hadoop -dfs get file . ; and see if that works

Comment: Could you please show how you're running the wordcount example? Have you checked, whether the job ran successfully - in the console and using job tracker's web interface?

Comment: I used the following command to execute bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.0.4.jar wordcount inputall/tempinput.txt /user/ravi/tempoutput2.txt

Answer (score 1):

The file in HDFS you are trying to cat is a directory (the flags column shows `drwxr-xr-x`). Hadoop jobs will typically output their result to a directory, with one file per reducer (or per mapper if you run a job with no reducers).

So ls the contents of that folder, you should see some part-r files - try and cat those files:

```
bin/hadoop dfs -cat /user/ravi/tempoutput.txt/part-r-*
```

Comment: Well if there is no error message then there is no output - try a `bin/hadoop dfs -ls /user/ravi/tempoutput.txt/` - does that show any files, and do the files have size > 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

The expected syntax for running the wordcount example is: `bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.0.4.jar wordcount <input_dir> <output_dir>`. It could be possible, that your wordcount did not process any data and thus you can't see any results.
Try running `bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.0.4.jar wordcount /user/ravi/inputall /user/ravi/output` followed by `bin/hadoop dfs -ls /user/ravi/output` to see the results.

Furthermore you should check the details of the map reduce yob execution after running it (either directly in console or using web interface). There should be detailed information about the number of processed input records/bytes. You could also browse the whole file system in your web browser: `http://localhost:50070/dfshealth.jsp`